# java convert to int

Tags: java

I am trying to convert to int like this, but I am getting an exception.

```
    String strHexNumber = "0x1";
    int decimalNumber = Integer.parseInt(strHexNumber, 16);
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0x1"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:458)
```

It would be a great help if someone can fix it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure - you need to get rid of the "0x" part if you want to use `parseInt`:

```
int parsed = Integer.parseInt("100", 16);
System.out.println(parsed); // 256
```

If you *know* your value will start with "0x" you can just use:

```
String prefixStripped = hexNumber.substring(2);
```

Otherwise, just test for it:

```
number = number.startsWith("0x") ? number.substring(2) : number;
```

Note that you should think about how negative numbers will be represented too.

EDIT: Adam's solution using `decode` will certainly work, but if you already know the radix then IMO it's clearer to state it explicitly than to have it inferred - particularly if it would surprise people for "035" to be treated as octal, for example. Each method is appropriate at different times, of course, so it's worth knowing about both. Pick whichever one handles your particular situation most cleanly and clearly.

Comment: Not necessary. See my solution.

Answer (score 5):

That's because the 0x prefix is not allowed. It's only a Java language thing.

```
String strHexNumber = "F777";
int decimalNumber = Integer.parseInt(strHexNumber, 16);
System.out.println(decimalNumber);
```

If you want to parse strings with leading 0x then use the .decode methods available on Integer, Long etc.

```
int value = Integer.decode("0x12AF");
System.out.println(value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Integer.parseInt can only parse strings that are formatted to look just like an int. So you can parse "0" or "12343" or "-56" but not "0x1".

Answer (score 0):

You need to strip off the `0x` from the front of the string before you ask the Integer class to parse it.  The `parseInt` method expects the string passed in to be only numbers/letters of the specified radix.

Answer (score 0):

try using this code here:-

```
import java.io.*;
 import java.lang.*;

public class  HexaToInteger{

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

   BufferedReader read = 

   new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

   System.out.println("Enter the hexadecimal value:!");

   String s = read.readLine();

   int i = Integer.valueOf(s, 16).intValue();

   System.out.println("Integer:=" + i);

   }

 }
```

Comment: well then the number format is wrong, cuz java dont recognize his 0x1 numericals.

Comment: The question that was asked was how to convert strings with 0x prefixes... not those without...

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, Integer is still expecting some kind of String of numbers. that x is really going to mess things up.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of the hex, you may need to use a BigInteger (you can probably skip the "L" check and trim in yours ;-) ):

```
        // Convert HEX to decimal
        if (category.startsWith("0X") && category.endsWith("L")) {
            category = new BigInteger(category.substring(2, category.length() - 1), 16).toString();
        } else if (category.startsWith("0X")) {
            category = new BigInteger(category.substring(2, category.length()), 16).toString();
        }
```