# convert hex string to byte not byte array

Tags: java, android, hex, byte

i needed to convert hex which i get from color code

```
int color = singleColor.getColor();

                String rgbString = "R: " + Color.red(color) + " B: " + Color.blue(color) + " G: " + Color.green(color);
                String hexRed = "0x" + Integer.toHexString(Color.red(color));
                String hexGreen = "0x" + Integer.toHexString(Color.green(color));
                String hexBlue= "0x" + Integer.toHexString(Color.blue(color));
                Log.e("hex string", hexRed + hexGreen + hexBlue);
```

log generated is........ 0xb30x120xff

which is completed i wanted

but i want to convert this in byte and then join them as byte array like this which is working completely ok

```
byte[] hex_txt = {(byte)0xff, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00};
sendData(hex_txt);
```

my question is how to convert this string to like this so i can send data....

```
byte byteRed = Byte.valueOf(hexRed);
```

this is not working number format exception also tried other solutions which are not working

advance thx for help

Comment: What is `hexRed` when the above gives you the `NumberFormatException`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [java convert to int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9670723/java-convert-to-int)

Comment: `valueOf` does not recognize `0x`.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9670723/java-convert-to-int) for some solutions.

Comment: number format exception occurs when i direct convert with hexred so thats problem when this occurs... so you are right about it but is there any difference between byte byteRed = Byte.valueof("ff") and i sendd thiss byteRed or convert thiss (byte)0xff ?

Comment: #1: If you want to use `valueOf` on a string of hex digits, you need to say `Byte.valueOf(yourString, 16)`.  #2: `Byte` is a signed type that goes from -128 to 127, so it will still fail if you give it `"ff"` because that is 255 and is out of range.  If you want to do it that way, use `Integer.valueOf` and then cast to a `Byte`.  (Actually you'll need to cast to an `(int)` to unbox the type first, then cast that to `(byte)`.)

Comment: can you give an example of that as i am getting confused ...is there difference between adding 0xff and just ff to byte ?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Some methods that convert strings to integers understand `0x` and some methods don't.  Are you having difficulty understanding that?  `valueOf` doesn't understand `0x`, but you can use it like `byte byteRed = (byte)(int)Integer.valueOf(substring(hexRed,2),16);`.

Comment: sorry my question was hexRed = "oxff"
byte byteRed = (byte)(int)Integer.valueOf(hexRed.substring(2),16); 
and 
byte byteRed = (byte)oxff; both are same ?

Comment: The first one will assign `byteRed` to `0xff`, which I think is what you want.

Answer (score -3):

You can only convert Strings to a byte array and vice versa.

```
        String example = "This is an example";
        byte[] bytes = example.getBytes();

        System.out.println("Text : " + example);
        System.out.println("Text [Byte Format] : " + bytes);
```

Google "convert String to byte" and you will find plenty on converting string to byte[]

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-string-to-byte-in-java/

Comment: The question has to do with converting strings that contain hexadecimal numbers in them.  `getBytes` does not do that.

Comment: can you please explain in which i have asked as i needed in specific format...you means  0xb30x120xff string to getbytes will work ?